# How do i connect second database if my first database connection faild using eval in perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I want connect to database using perl but if my database connection is faild then i want connect to my second database using eval function.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $dbh = eval { 
    DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:host=$host1;database=$database", 
        $user, $password, { 'RaiseError' => 1 });
};
if (!$dbh) {
    $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:host=$host2;database=$database", 
        $user, $password, { 'RaiseError' => 1 });
}
```